# Differences in Hibernate Entity Fetching Behaviour with MySQL vs. PostgreSQL (Spring Boot 3.1, Hibernate 6.2)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

When using Hibernate with MySQL, I've observed that once an entity is fetched, it appears to be cached and reused in subsequent queries within the same session, avoiding unnecessary joins. However, when switching to PostgreSQL, the same entity is not reused from the cache; instead, it is fetched anew with each query, resulting in multiple joins for the same entity. This behavior occurs even though the entity is associated with the user and should be available in Hibernate's first-level cache (I guess?). This leads to big performance hits due to the increased number of joins and database calls, e.g. around 40 rows with MySQL compared to 10k rows with Postgres.

Here's a specific example to illustrate the issue:

MySQL Behavior: Upon fetching a User entity that has a relationship with a Company entity, the Company is fetched and cached. Subsequent queries within the same transaction reuse the cached Company, and no additional joins are made to fetch this entity again.

PostgreSQL Behavior: The same User entity fetch results in the Company entity being fetched and cached. However, unlike with MySQL, subsequent queries within the same transaction do not reuse the Company from the cache. Instead, Hibernate performs additional joins to refetch the Company, ignoring the cache. This repeats with other entities being fetched and joined quite often resulting in many rows fetched and mapped.

I tried to compare the generated queries for MySQL and Postgres, here is an example query, other queries generated have the same behaviour:

MySQL:

```sql
select
    u1_0.id,
    u1_0.automatic_time_tracking_enabled,
    c1_0.user_id,
    c1_0.id,
    c1_0.deleted,
    c1_0.from_timestamp,
    c1_0.to_timestamp,
    c2_0.id,
    a1_0.id,
    a1_0.city,
    a1_0.country,
    a1_0.deleted,
    a1_0.state,
    a1_0.street,
    a1_0.zip_code,
    c2_0.deleted,
    e1_0.company_id,
    e1_0.enabled_module,
    c2_0.identifier,
    c2_0.latitude,
    c2_0.longitude,
    c2_0.name,
    c2_0.registration_number,
    s1_0.id,
    s1_0.deleted,
    s1_0.show_task_ranking,
    s1_0.show_vineyard_no,
    u1_0.deleted,
    u1_0.email,
    u1_0.firstname,
    g1_0.user_id,
    g1_0.id,
    g1_0.deleted,
    g2_0.id,
    g2_0.company_id,
    g2_0.deleted,
    g2_0.group_leader_id,
    g2_0.name,
    u1_0.images3key,
    u1_0.is_archived,
    u1_0.lastname,
    u1_0.location_consent,
    u1_0.location_consent_timestamp,
    u1_0.nickname,
    u1_0.notes,
    u1_0.password,
    u1_0.phone_number,
    u1_0.role,
    u1_0.small_images3key,
    u1_0.temp_password,
    u1_0.username,
    w1_0.user_id,
    w1_0.working_days
from
    user u1_0
        left join
    calculation_blocker c1_0
    on u1_0.id=c1_0.user_id
        left join
    company c2_0
    on c2_0.id=u1_0.company_id
        left join
    address a1_0
    on a1_0.id=c2_0.address_id
        left join
    company_module_config e1_0
    on c2_0.id=e1_0.company_id
        left join
    settings s1_0
    on s1_0.id=c2_0.settings_id
        left join
    group_user g1_0
    on u1_0.id=g1_0.user_id
        left join
    group g2_0
    on g2_0.id=g1_0.group_id
        left join
    working_days w1_0
    on u1_0.id=w1_0.user_id
where
    u1_0.id=?;
```

Postgres:

```sql
select
    u1_0.id,
    u1_0.automatic_time_tracking_enabled,
    c1_0.user_id,
    c1_0.id,
    c1_0.deleted,
    c1_0.from_timestamp,
    c1_0.to_timestamp,
    c2_0.id,
    a1_0.id,
    a1_0.city,
    a1_0.country,
    a1_0.deleted,
    a1_0.state,
    a1_0.street,
    a1_0.zip_code,
    c2_0.deleted,
    e1_0.company_id,
    e1_0.enabled_module,
    c2_0.identifier,
    c2_0.latitude,
    c2_0.longitude,
    c2_0.name,
    c2_0.registration_number,
    s1_0.id,
    s1_0.deleted,
    s1_0.show_task_ranking,
    s1_0.show_vineyard_no,
    u1_0.deleted,
    u1_0.email,
    u1_0.firstname,
    g1_0.user_id,
    g1_0.id,
    g1_0.deleted,
    g2_0.id,
    c3_0.id,
    a2_0.id,
    a2_0.city,
    a2_0.country,
    a2_0.deleted,
    a2_0.state,
    a2_0.street,
    a2_0.zip_code,
    c3_0.deleted,
    e2_0.company_id,
    e2_0.enabled_module,
    c3_0.identifier,
    c3_0.latitude,
    c3_0.longitude,
    c3_0.name,
    c3_0.registration_number,
    s2_0.id,
    s2_0.deleted,
    s2_0.show_task_ranking,
    s2_0.show_vineyard_no,
    g2_0.deleted,
    l1_0.id,
    l1_0.automatic_time_tracking_enabled,
    c4_0.id,
    a3_0.id,
    a3_0.city,
    a3_0.country,
    a3_0.deleted,
    a3_0.state,
    a3_0.street,
    a3_0.zip_code,
    c4_0.deleted,
    e3_0.company_id,
    e3_0.enabled_module,
    c4_0.identifier,
    c4_0.latitude,
    c4_0.longitude,
    c4_0.name,
    c4_0.registration_number,
    s3_0.id,
    s3_0.deleted,
    s3_0.show_task_ranking,
    s3_0.show_vineyard_no,
    l1_0.deleted,
    l1_0.email,
    l1_0.firstname,
    l1_0.images3key,
    l1_0.is_archived,
    l1_0.lastname,
    l1_0.location_consent,
    l1_0.location_consent_timestamp,
    l1_0.nickname,
    l1_0.notes,
    l1_0.password,
    l1_0.phone_number,
    l1_0.role,
    l1_0.small_images3key,
    l1_0.temp_password,
    l1_0.username,
    w1_0.user_id,
    w1_0.working_days,
    g2_0.name,
    u1_0.images3key,
    u1_0.is_archived,
    u1_0.lastname,
    u1_0.location_consent,
    u1_0.location_consent_timestamp,
    u1_0.nickname,
    u1_0.notes,
    u1_0.password,
    u1_0.phone_number,
    u1_0.role,
    u1_0.small_images3key,
    u1_0.temp_password,
    u1_0.username,
    w2_0.user_id,
    w2_0.working_days
from
    user u1_0
        left join
    calculation_blocker c1_0
    on u1_0.id=c1_0.user_id
        left join
    company c2_0
    on c2_0.id=u1_0.company_id
        left join
    address a1_0
    on a1_0.id=c2_0.address_id
        left join
    company_module_config e1_0
    on c2_0.id=e1_0.company_id
        left join
    settings s1_0
    on s1_0.id=c2_0.settings_id
        left join
    group_user g1_0
    on u1_0.id=g1_0.user_id
        left join
    group g2_0
    on g2_0.id=g1_0.group_id
        left join
    company c3_0
    on c3_0.id=g2_0.company_id
        left join
    address a2_0
    on a2_0.id=c3_0.address_id
        left join
    company_module_config e2_0
    on c3_0.id=e2_0.company_id
        left join
    settings s2_0
    on s2_0.id=c3_0.settings_id
        left join
    user l1_0
    on l1_0.id=g2_0.group_leader_id
        left join
    company c4_0
    on c4_0.id=l1_0.company_id
        left join
    address a3_0
    on a3_0.id=c4_0.address_id
        left join
    company_module_config e3_0
    on c4_0.id=e3_0.company_id
        left join
    settings s3_0
    on s3_0.id=c4_0.settings_id
        left join
    working_days w1_0
    on l1_0.id=w1_0.user_id
        left join
    working_days w2_0
    on u1_0.id=w2_0.user_id
where
    u1_0.id=?;
```

Please ignore any data-structure specific issues.
Some questions I am having:

- Why is there a significant difference in the query optimization between MySQL and PostgreSQL when using Hibernate?
- Is this behavior influenced by the database-specific dialects in Hibernate, JDBC driver implementation, or something else?
- Has anyone else experienced similar behavior, and what were the potential solutions or explanations provided?
- Besides setting the FetchType to LAZY for all associations, are there other configurations or optimizations that can help achieve consistent performance across databases?
- Did I do something stupid that promotes this behaviour? - At this point, any suggestion is welcome, I want to understand why there is such a big discrepancy.

Comment: `40 rows with MySQL compared to 10k rows with Postgres`, that is really strange, why does one brand of database have way more records than the other brand?

Comment: @FrankHeikens the data inserted are the same, but after inserting hibernate creates queries with many joins, in MySQL the resulting row count was 40 compared to postgres resulting in 10k rows.

My understanding is, that Hibernate with MySQL does 'some' caching and realizes that an entity was already fetched and uses that along the way / in future queries.

Comment: In case of MySQL Hibernate tries to limit amount of joins using [`hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size=2` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146492/understanding-hibernate-hibernate-max-fetch-depth-and-hibernate-default-batch-fe), [github link](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5fa08123b31e017f9f57c96e98b40890b6df8c5d/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java#L214C1-L218C3)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thank you for the link, it exactly describes the problem experiencing with Postgres. I still don't understand why there is a difference for the queries in MySQL and Postgres, but hibernate.max_fetch_depth did fix the problem (for now)! Thank you!

Comment: just someones were too optimistic about PostgreSQL (or too pessimistic about MySQL), however it does not mean you are right in you decisions.